# Cakephp - Disable CSRF to using api in android app

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, csrf-protection, cakephp-3.7

Here we have cakephp version 3.7.2.

Cakephp set Csrf as cookie in browsers but we want call Api from mobile application [Android] which don't have cookie to set.

I disabled Csrf in my ***localhost*** successfully by commenting:

```
$routes->applyMiddleware('csrf'); //configs/routes.php
```

And after it cookie doesn't set automatically.

**My problem is when i publish it on the server (online) the project cookie still set in the browser.**

**Note:** we used SSL Domain (https)

Answer (score 2):

In Cakephp to disable CSRF middleware you have to comment `CsrfProtectionMiddleware`  in `/src/Application.php`

```
   public function middleware($middlewareQueue)
      {
           $middlewareQueue
        // Catch any exceptions in the lower layers,
        // and make an error page/response
        ->add(ErrorHandlerMiddleware::class)

        // Handle plugin/theme assets like CakePHP normally does.
        ->add(new AssetMiddleware([
            'cacheTime' => Configure::read('Asset.cacheTime')
        ]))

        // Add routing middleware.
        // Routes collection cache enabled by default, to disable route caching
        // pass null as cacheConfig, example: `new RoutingMiddleware($this)`
        // you might want to disable this cache in case your routing is extremely simple
        ->add(new RoutingMiddleware($this, '_cake_routes_'));


        // Add csrf middleware.   // comment these lines
        //            ->add(new CsrfProtectionMiddleware([
        //                'httpOnly' => true
        //            ]));

        return $middlewareQueue;
     }
```

[Cakephp -> Middleware -> Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Middleware](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-middleware)

Hope this will help!

Comment: This version didn't have `CsrfProtectionMiddleware` in Application.php, and moved into routes.php

Comment: The only way i can do it's downgrade cakephp to 3.6.2 and doing your answer and it will work in localhost and  server.

Comment: If there's nowhere in your code that enables the CSRF middleware, then it's not going to have any effect. If it's having some effect, then it's enabled somewhere. It's hard to help when the only symptom you've described is that the cookie exists; that could even be left over from before you disabled it?

Comment: @Maher this may be cache issue. Please try to remove your cache first and then try.

Comment: I am using cakephp 3 and there I didn't found any such code. However, I disabled it via AppController.php but it still didn't work out. Any further suggestions?

Comment: @GregSchmidt As you are saying that it's not gonna have any effect but it is having in my case.

Comment: I was just saying that if it's having some effect, it's because CSRF is enabled somewhere.